# What does it mean when an integrand is singular at x = 0?

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

the integrand $f(x) = x^{−1}sin(x^{−1}log(x))$ has infinitely many oscillations in the interval [0, 1] and is also singular at x = 0.

What does it mean "singular at x = 0"?

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "singular at $x=0$" refers to the fact that the integrand has a [singularity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics)) at $x=0$. In particular, our function fails to be defined at $x=0$.